# Getting long CSS elements and changing them with jQuery (i.e. ::before, :after, :first-child) .

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have this CSS query here:

```
last-ns > .col-2:first-child > a::before {
  content: "";
  border-left: 1px solid #aaa;
  position: absolute;
  height: 448px;
  left: 5px;
}
```

I want to use jQuery to adjust the `height` value of that specific `a::before` element; however, I have no idea how to grab that using jQuery...

I'm used to the typical jQuery form of changing CSS:

```
$("p").css ({
    "background-color": "yellow", "font-size": "200%"
});
```

But I am unsure how to change more complex CSS queries such as my `last-ns > .col-2:first-child > a::before`.

Any idea how to do this? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

**edit**

My overall goal is to extend the height of that element when a separate element is clicked.

Comment: That answer was not helpful for my particular issue.

Comment: In one of the answers to that question it says: `You'd think this would be a simple question to answer, with everything else that jQuery can do. Unfortunately, the problem comes down to a technical issue: css :after and :before rules aren't part of the DOM, and therefore can't be altered using jQuery's DOM methods.`

Comment: Since :after and :before aren't part of the DOM, couldn't you just append a class (someClassName) to this anchor (however you are triggering the adjusting of the height, hover perhaps?) and then have your someClasName::before CSS already in place? Then the opposite trigger to simply remove that class?

Answer (score -1):

Dunno if this helps you, but... instead of manipulating styles in jQuery add custom class to DOM and move your changes to css.

JS:

```
$('.last-ns > .col-2:first-child > a').addClass('foo');
```

CSS:

```
.last-ns > .col-2:first-child > a.foo::before {
    border-color: red;
}
```

Simple example in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3v5zbpqm/